# CanCanCan view only if has attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

Im using CanCanCan to manage my authorizations pages.

This is how is set my Abilities page:

```
class Ability
 include CanCan::Ability
 def initialize(user)

#return if user.nil?
if user.nil? 
  can :read, User
  can :read, Talent, {is_major: false}
else
```

A User has_one Talent. And a Talent has a method called: is_major. This method checks if the talent have more then 18 years old.

I want that, a User that is not logged in on the app, can only read a Talent if this Talent is_major.

How can I setup it on CanCanCan?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with CanCanCan, but does something like this work? __can [:read], Talent, is_major: False__

Comment: the problem is that is_major its a method from my model. Not a column on the database

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was only a sintax:

If I add:

```
if user.nil? 
  can :read, User
  can :read, Talent, is_major?: true
else
```

It works.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to [define the ability with block syntax](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/define_abilities_with_blocks.md) since `is_major?` is a model method.

```rb
can :read, Talent do |talent|
    talent.is_major?
end
```